# Programa C++ para dia da semana (com exemplo de código)

Tags: c, c++

Sabe-se que o dia da semana de uma data fornecida entre 1° de março de 1700 e 28 de fevereiro de 2100 pode ser determinado através do seguinte método:

```
n=int(365.25∗g)+int(30.6∗f)−621049+d

ds=round(frac(n/7)∗7)+Δ+1

g={a−1, m≤2
  {a, m>2

f={m+13, m <= 2
  {m+1, m>2

Δ={2,n<36523
  {1,36523≤n<73048
  {0,n≥73048
```

O dia da semana (ds) é representado por 1 se for domingo, 2 se for segunda-feira, e assim por diante. Faça um programa que leia o dia, mês e ano e forneça o dia da semana correspondente;

sei que devo utilizar modf() para o frac(n/7), para obter a parte fracionária. Até agora não encontrei lógica, pois o dia da semana sempre acaba sendo 01.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;

int main(){

    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
    int ds;
    int g;
    int f;
    int delta;
    int n;
    float frac;
    float intpart;

    cin >> dia >> mes >> ano;

    if(mes > 2){
        g = ano;
        f = mes + 1;
    }else if(mes <= 2){
        g = ano - 1;
        f = mes + 13;
    }

    n = int(365.25 * g) + int(30.6 * f) - 621049 + dia;

    cout << n << endl;

    if(n < 36523){
        delta = 2;
    }else if( 36523 <= n and n < 73048){
        delta = 1;
    }else if(n >= 73048){
        delta = 0;
    }

    cout << delta << endl;
    frac = modf(n/7, &intpart);

    ds = round(frac * 7) + delta + 1;

    cout << ds << endl;

    switch (ds){
        case 1:
            cout << "domingo" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "segunda-feira" << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "terca-feira" << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "quarta-feira"  << endl;    
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "quinta-feira" << endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << "sexta-feira" << endl;
        case 7:
            cout << "sabado" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aqui: `frac = modf(n/7, &intpart);` faça ou `frac = modf((float) n / 7, &intpart);` ou `frac = modf(n / 7.0, &intpart);` para forçar a operação em ponto flutuante e não uma operação entre inteiros.

Comment: muitíssimo obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você sempre entra no `case 1:`, pois sua variável `frac` está retornando 0 para a variável `ds`.

Isto está acontecendo porque você não fez um [casting](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/footnotes/cast.html) de `int` para `float` dentro da função [modf](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modf-in-cc/).

Seu código corrigido ficará assim:

```
frac = modf((float)n/7, &intpart);
```

Observe que o recomendado para operar números float é a função modff:
[modf, modff, modfl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/modf)

> Mas por que sua variável frac estava retornado 0 ?

Porque na divisão entre números inteiros( sua variável `n` é do tipo int) a parte **fracionária é eliminada**.

Por isto sua função `modf` sempre retornava 0 para a sua variável `ds`, pois não havia parte fracionária!

Comment: cara, valeu... tô inciando em C++... não sabia que deveria forçar a tipagem

Comment: tentei editar a linha e mesmo assim retorna 01, domingo

Comment: Tentou mudar os valores iniciais de dia, mês e ano? Aqui retornou correto

Comment: faltou forçar o 7.0

Comment: Boa! Precisando de mais ajuda, abra novas perguntas!

Comment: A resposta está errada. Na expressão float(n/7), o programa primeiro realiza uma integer division de n/7 (que provavelmente vai dar 0) e depois constroi um float com o valor 0.

Comment: @v.Santos verdade o correto seria (float)n/7. Já vou corrigir

Comment: O correto seria ou (float) n / 7. Ou o bem mais simples n/7.0. Que me parece que foi a solução adotada pelo @Alce de Terno.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver o problema deve-se usar do casting para float, evitando int em todo caso

```
frac = modf(float(n/7.0), &intpart);
```

tanto float() casting quanto forçar 7.0 como divisor

Comment: float() não é casting. float() funciona como um construtor (embora, a rigor, não seja um construtor). Ele apenas constrói um objeto do tipo float com o número passado como parâmetro. Para realizar um cast, utiliza-se (float) - enfatizo, não float() - e isso apenas por compatibilidade com a linguagem C, pois, a rigor, C++ tem seus próprios operadores de casting.

Answer (score -3):

costumo usar assim:

```
uint8_t RTCWeekDayNum(uint32_t nYear, uint8_t nMonth, uint8_t nDay)
{
  uint32_t year = 0, weekday = 0;
  year = 2000 + nYear;
  
  if(nMonth < 3)
  {
     weekday = (((23 * nMonth)/9) + nDay + 4 + year + ((year-1)/4) - ((year-1)/100) + ((year-1)/400)) % 7;
  }
  else
  {
     weekday = (((23 * nMonth)/9) + nDay + 4 + year + (year/4) - (year/100) + (year/400) - 2 ) % 7; 
  }
  return((uint8_t)weekday);
}
```